# Is it possible to create a binding redirect at runtime?

Tags: .net, assembly-resolution

Once an application has started is there a way to create a binding redirect that will apply to all future assembly loads?

Comment: Why do you need this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean by all future loads?

Comment: @darin. so is that a "i dont know"? it is a fairly convoluted case and not really worth explaining here.

Comment: @František assemblies load on domand. So I want to control binding for when assemblies are loaded during the life of the application

Comment: @Simon I am just asking for clarification on what you are trying to achieve. That's all.

Comment: @darin i am trying to get around an obscure file lock issue to do with a VS addin. forcing a binding to fail may give me a back door to workaround the issue. this is a greatly summarised description :)

Comment: @Simon: is it something you could use `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event for?

Comment: @František AppDomain.AssemblyResolve only fires for an assembly failure. so no it does not help

Comment: @Simon, I've got this exact same issue now. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @CoryNelson no. I marked Gaels answer as correct because it seems like the correct way to go. but I was not able to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *could* be possible using ICLRHostBindingPolicyManager::ModifyApplicationPolicy, but I've never tried myself. Note that this is a CLR-level interface, so you can't load policies for individual AppDomains (which is why it is not used by PostSharp yet).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164378.aspx

Answer (score 12):

Sorry for responding to an old post, but this blog has a much better answer to the question. Hope someone finds it useful.

My use case: doing a binding redirect from a COM interop assembly invoked by a classic ASP application.

http://blog.slaks.net/2013-12-25/redirecting-assembly-loads-at-runtime/

This function from the post in question will do what you want:

```
public static void RedirectAssembly(string shortName, Version targetVersion, string publicKeyToken) {
    ResolveEventHandler handler = null;

    handler = (sender, args) => {
        // Use latest strong name & version when trying to load SDK assemblies
        var requestedAssembly = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
        if (requestedAssembly.Name != shortName)
            return null;

        Debug.WriteLine("Redirecting assembly load of " + args.Name
                      + ",\tloaded by " + (args.RequestingAssembly == null ? "(unknown)" : args.RequestingAssembly.FullName));

        requestedAssembly.Version = targetVersion;
        requestedAssembly.SetPublicKeyToken(new AssemblyName("x, PublicKeyToken=" + publicKeyToken).GetPublicKeyToken());
        requestedAssembly.CultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve -= handler;

        return Assembly.Load(requestedAssembly);
    };
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += handler;
}
```